# Formatting selected date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am displaying `datepicker` without an input. I want to get the selected date and format it to `dd-mm-yy` but it's not working.

[image]

```js
$(function() {
    var selectedDate = $("#inline-calendar").datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    }).datepicker("setDate", "now").datepicker("getDate");

    console.log(selectedDate)
});
```

```html
<div id="inline-calendar"></div>
```

The output of the above code is `Sat Sep 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)`

Comment: Are you using jQuery datepicker ?

Comment: Bootstrap datepicker v1.7.0

Comment: @lurker No it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.data` attributes in bootstrap `datepicker` to get the value of the date on the calendar using `getFormattedDate`

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inline-calendar").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  }).datepicker("setDate", "now").datepicker("getDate");
    
  //get date value
  let getDate = $("#inline-calendar").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('dd-mm-yy');

  console.log(getDate) //12-09-20
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="inline-calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the other line work. Sorry for having an additional request, but can you also specify the `onSelect` for the datepicker? My code is unable to trigger it.

Comment: @Emerald You are welcome. So you want to trigger date change on select and get the selected value in the console.log each time you click a new date ?

Comment: Oh! I managed to get it work by using your method! `$("#inline-calendar").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
     let getDate = $("#inline-calendar").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('dd-mm-yyyy');
     console.log(getDate);
    })` Thank you very much for your help!